# Dynamically constructed if statement in one string variable

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am blacking out over issue and I am convinced I am thinking too complex about this, but summarized, my issue is about this:

```
// imagine this variable is dynamically filled by a loop with conditions inside
var condition = varA + " == " + varB + " && " + varC + " == " + varD;

if (condition) {
    // something
}
```

So it doesn't check whether `varA` equals `varB` and `varC` equals `varD` as what I intended, but instead it just sees it as a string and that appears to be always true anyway. I don't want, I want to see it actually checking whether `varA` equals `varB` etc.

Is there a way to parse this `statement` into something that actually *can* be a 'legit' if condition?

Thanks!

Comment: you could use `eval()` but it's generally frowned upon. still why not just write that if statement? it doesn't really make sense to build it this way

Comment: Have you tried looping through two variables at a time?  `runningBool = runningBool && varX == varY`. At the end of the loop, `runningBool` will be true or false.

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak I get what you think, as `if (varA == varB && ...)` would normally work as well indeed, but that won't help in my situation as in this if-statement the amount of conditions varies per case. It could be that the condition `varA == varB` is omitted dynamically through filtering so only `varC == carD` remains. Case is too that every (dynamically added) condition needs to be true. I wonder if this is the way to go to accomplish this anyway, so it's the question how else I would be able to do this.

Comment: like I said you can use `eval()` but why not just use a switch statement and handle the amount of variables with separate cases?

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak I think I thought about the same as what you wrote, with the switch-statements, but what if the amount of conditions is more than 3? In that case I'd have to make a lot of hard coded different cases for each possible condition, as A==B && C==D && E==F could also be A==B && E==F and so on. Do I misinterpret you here?

Comment: well if you store the variables in an array you could handle them as pairs so `[[a,b],[c,d],[e,f]]` then just `.forEach()` evaluate `if(arr[0] === arr[1])`, store those results in an array `[false, true, false]` for example and then evaluate those as need e.g. `arr[0] === arr[1]` is now `a === b && c === d` hope that makes sense obv not perfect I would have to see a lot more code to whip up something suitable

Answer (score 1):

why not just do

```
if(varA  ==  varB  &&  varC ==varD){
//do something
}
```

edit

maybe try using safe-eval. its a third party package but APPEARS to be an improvement on eval.

Comment: The comment in his/her code at the top suggests that the condition is dynamically populated. If it were just `varA == varB && varC == varD` this would be a non-issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what your trying to do. You are trying to look at a number of comparisons and determine, in the end, if all comparisons were truly true.

In this case you can actually just keep building your condition out as in the following:

```
var a = 1, b = 1, c = 3, d = 3, e = 5, f = 6; 
var condition = a === b; // condition is true
condition = condition && c === d; // condition is still true
condition = condition && e === f; // condition is now and forever false
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your condition variable is that it's not checking for equality between your variables. The whole condition variable is being read as a string because it sees the == and && as strings and ends up concatenating them together.

I suggest writing your if statement like so:

```
if (varA === varB && varB === varC && varC === varD) {
  // do something
}
```

That way, you're checking if varA is equal to varB and varB is equal to varC, etc. Using the triple equals also ensures that the variables are of the type value type (i.e. string, boolean, number). Hope this helps.

Comment: I know about the existance of ===, thanks for that and right you are, but that is not the general issue here. The issue is about the dynamic condition, where varA could suddenly not check varB if it would be equal (while it could with the rest).